# Need help on simplifying Calculus 2 problem

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Im wondering how

$$\frac{1}{4}\int(1-2\cos2x+\frac{1+\cos4x}{2})\,dx$$

simplifies to:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int(\frac{3}{2}-2\cos2x + \frac{1}{2}\cos4x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 + \frac{1+\cos (4x)}{2}=\left(1+\frac12 \right)+\frac{\cos(4x)}{2}$$